# Unable to run WebdrverIO coe (using Visual VS code V1.67.0 with Node.js V18.0 ) in windows 10 in hp laptop using Chrome driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

After configuring WebdrverIO(using Visual VS code V1.67.0 with Node.js V18.0 ) in windows 10 in hp laptop , I am getting following error while running through Chrome driver::                                                                                                                                                      ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: write EPROTO 085C0000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation
disabled:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:922:

I did not come up with any solution , need help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.